# Spark job inserting data to cassandra works in client mode, not in cluster

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a spark streaming job which workes perfectly well in client mode. It reads data from Kafka, processes it, and inserts to Cassandra.

When I change the deploy mode to cluster, application is running, but data does not get flushed to Cassandra. I inspected all the logs, but there are no errors.

Anyway, in WEB UI, I found some really interesting issue:
[image]

It looks like none of mine batches in a stream finishes at all, they are all active!!!

So what might be the problem?

**EDITED**

Here is some code

```
val measurements = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[
  Array[Byte],
  Array[Byte],
  DefaultDecoder,
  DefaultDecoder](ssc, kafkaConfig, Set("wattio"
))
  .map {
    case (k, v) => {
      val decoder = new AvroDecoder[WattioMeasure](null,
        WattioMeasure.SCHEMA$)
      decoder.fromBytes(v)
    }
  }

WattioFunctions.run(WattioFunctions.processWattioRaw(measurements))
     ((rdd: RDD[WattioTenantRaw], t: Time) => {
    rdd.cache()
    val differentTenants = rdd.map(a => a.tenant).distinct().collect()
    differentTenants.foreach(tenant => {
      val keyspace = tenant + "_readings"
      rdd.filter(a => a.tenant == tenant).map(s => s.wattioRaw).saveToCassandra(keyspace, "table")
    })
    rdd.unpersist(true)
  }
)

ssc.checkpoint("/tmp")
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: could you add your code to the question?

Comment: @maasg: I added some code to my question

Comment: Hi, Can you confirm if you set "spark.cassandra.connection.host" property in configuration.?

Comment: Yes, it is set to private IP of the virtual machine

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors on the logs on the workers? I'd expect that something is going wrong with reaching the cassandra cluster from the worker nodes.

Comment: Actually, I had this error in my driver log:


Exception in thread "streaming-job-executor-132" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/ColumnSelector

It looks like worker does not have access to spark-cassandra-connector or something

Comment: @Srdjan Nikitovic  So, this question could be closed?

Comment: @maasg yes, it can be closed